# Magento API call in Ionic3 Application

Tags: rest, magento, soap, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic. Did so many searches but could not able to get clarification. I just wanted to know whether is it possible to consume Magento Soap and Rest APIs in Ionic Project. My scenario is I have built Magento based ecommerce website which provides Soap API output(XML) and Rest API which provides JSON output.Now i need to call the APIs in Ionic App. Just wanted to know the possibilities in which version of ionic it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling i came to know that ionic consumes and kind of api. I can able to successfully consume remote api in Ionic 3